# JPQL comparing Entities

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I have a database which stores (among others) Presentations, which is mapped using JPA. These presentations have a starting time, and an endtime.

I'd like know whether there's an overlap before adding a new presentation. I am currently doing this with a query that selects all presentations with the same room and same date.

I'd like to add the time to this. My times are made using a custom java.sql.Time subclass (I need it for a custom constructor). I obviously don't want to map those in the database. Now I'd like to check whether a certain time is before or after another.

I'm currently using the query `SELECT p FROM Presentatie p WHERE p.lokaal.code = :lokaal AND p.dag = :dag AND ( p.begin <= :einde OR p.einde >= :begin)` but that is flawed because it cannot compare Time classes (my guess that it evaluates to NULL, which would explain the zero-length resultset)

I don't know how to do this. I tried adding an `int time` to the `Time` class, but I can't reach it as it's not mapped using JPA.

I'd also like to know how it checks `p.dag = :dag`, is it equivalent to `dag == dag2`or `dag.equals(dag2)`? And how does it compare the time? `time > time2` (but this doesn't compile in Java, so I'm guessing it goes to `time.compareTo(time2)>0`?

Comment: Since `:einde` and `:begin` are the parameters that you are passing, why don't convert those to the same datatype that the column in the database is represented by, before you pass them to the query, making them comparable?

Comment: I give the same objects with them, and as it is a subclass of java.sql.Time, it is comparable. This should work then right? I am probably missing multiple things here